# How to share and open local folder path from Outlook

Tags: windows, outlook, ms-office

Following folder path, I'd like to share as a **hyperlink** with my team through outlook.

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\
```

So, they could open it with just one click from the outlook. But when the hyperlink is clicked, the outlook does not open the folder. Is there a way to open local folder path through the outlook?

Comment: This is not the way you share Windows resources. If you want to share certain folder, change sharing properties of this folder and send the location of this share instead. The link which work would look like: \\your_computer_name\path\to\shared\folder

Comment: I need user to open their local drive path of C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\ by just clicking the hyperlink. I don't have a list of their computer names, I'm wondering is there any alternative?

Comment: In this case I believe you would just need to provide the recipient with instructions how to reach this location as well as how to make it visible in Windows Explorer (by default the location is hidden). Interesting question through.